# Liquibase over SSH: Unexpected error running Liquibase: <file> does not exist

Tags: liquibase

We have been using Liquibase successfully for about six months. I'm moving to a new CI/CD pipeline using CircleCI and running into an error when running `liquibase update` over SSH.

Here's the command (after many iterations and much exploration of Liquibase documentation):
`ssh $SSH_USER@$TEST_JOB_SSH_HOST "cd /var/www/html/liquibase ; liquibase --url=jdbc:$TEST_DB_URL/$TEST_DB_SCHEMA?user=$TEST_DB_USERNAME --username=$TEST_DB_USERNAME --password="\""$TEST_DB_PASSWORD"\"" --changelog-file=cl-main.xml --search-path=.,./ update --log-level 1"`

The result:

[image]

However, the file does exist and can be seen here:

[image]

It was successfully executed several months ago using our old approach. Now I think Liquibase is just parsing files and somehow failing, likely because it's running from a different directory.

Here's a snippet from the changeset file:

```
<sqlFile dbms="mysql, mariadb"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    endDelimiter=";"
    path="/../data/regional_integration_details-ingest_day-01.sql"
    relativeToChangelogFile="true"
    splitStatements="true"
    stripComments="true"/>
```

I **think** the issue is the leading slash.

The command I pasted above was based on reviewing this help document: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/how-liquibase-finds-files.html

I'm struggling with the proper syntax to include in the `--search-path` parameter -- if that's even the correct parameter -- to make this work.

The nuclear option (yet to be tested) is to update all of our changesets, removing the leading slash. I'd prefer not to go that route.

Suggestions?

**Edit 1**

Updating to mention that the first four changesets are parsed successfully. They have path values like `../dirname/sqlscript_00.sql`. Liquibase chokes on the first script with `/../dirname/sqlscript_01.sql`.

Also, we have no problems running Liquibase in local development, when we cd to `/var/www/html/liquibase` in our Docker containers and execute the `liquibase update` command.

**Edit 2**

Having CircleCI SSH directly into the server doesn't work, as it doesn't carry the variables over with it.
[image]

Passing the commands via SSH preserves those variables.

[image]

Comment: With a peer's assistance, we still couldn't get Liquibase to cooperate. I edited all changeset files, dropping the leading `/`. With that change, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase removed support for absolute paths in v4.x.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. Unfortunately, I'm still confused as to why Liquibase was able to find the files on one machine but not another, both on v4.x. Regardless, we gave up after realizing it was behaving differently on two different machines and decided to just update all changeset files.